# What is the main difference between the Nikon 55-200mm VR lens and the newer version the VRII?

Tags: lens, nikon

Despite the obvious differences, price and weight, what is the main differences between these two lenses?

```
Nikon 55-200mm VR f/4-5.6   - 334g ~€150
Nikon 55-200mm VRII f/4-5.6 - 296g ~€300/350.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to find an article related to my questions.

Apparently what was improved in the newer version was:

- Zoom lock button
- SIC – Super Integrated Coating.

[Source](http://phototribune.com/2015/01/13/nikkor-55-200mm-vr-ii-worth-upgrade/)